# If I make a object enter a planet's gravity it hits the surface with huge velocity, where is it gaining k.e. from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

If I make a object enter a planet's gravity range,it hits the surface with huge velocity,where is it gaining k.e. from?
is it from the potential energy that it gained when it is separated from the planet  at the big bang?

Comment: The energy is not entirely from from the Big Bang since a lot of the material had to come from supernovas. This would mean that some of the energy came from the supernovas separating the dust that makes up the objects.

Comment: So can I gain energy that way? There is nothing wrong in my analysis right? Except that it's not practically feasible. Is it possible in future the we may gain energy this way?

Comment: Yes, you can harvest energy from the falling objects, if they hit the targets.

Comment: Post it as an answer

Comment: So that I can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy is not entirely from from the Big Bang since a lot of the material had to come from supernovas. This would mean that some of the energy came from the supernovas separating the dust that makes up the objects.

Yes, you can harvest energy from the falling objects, if they fall onto the targets.

Answer (score 2):

Total energy is conserved. Let $E$ stand for total energy. Let $T$ stand for kinetic energy. Let $U% stand for potential energy.

$E = T + U$

If $T$ increases and $E$ is constant (which it is in a closed system due to conservation of energy), then $U$ must decrease. Simply put, the kinetic comes from the potential energy.

[image]

Potential energy comes from configuration or position. In this case, it comes from the position of the ball in  gravitational field.

Since, $E$ is constant, you could get energy from having things fall to earth. This energy is not unlimited, however. Once the object is falling, all of its energy is becoming kinetic. To lift it back up, you must counter act the potential energy, requiring energy.

Comment: That i know. But Where is the p.e from?

Comment: @dushyanth  It comes from the positional of an object in the gravitational field.

Comment: Is the p.e always there.Can I gain energy by just pushing things into a planet's gravity using this phenomenon as asked in the question?

Comment: @dushyanth You can consider the potential energy as the *work* that gravity does. If a force is moving an object, then this force is doing work on the object, and this is exactly what gravity does. Since this is a *reversible* process that is *conservative* (no loss of energy along the way) we call that work *potential energy*. Same goes for elastic potential energy, electric potential energy or any other kind - they are all just the work being done. By doing work on the falling object, gravity is *adding energy* to the object in the form of *kinetic energy* in this case.